# How to pass a vector as parameter to a c++ library from a CLI/C++ Wrapper?

Tags: vector, c++-cli, wrapper, unmanaged, mixed-mode

I have found similar questions but none that worked for my situation, so I am asking my own.

I want to use a library function that takes a pointer to a std::vector, and fills it with data.

I already have a C++/CLI Wrapper set up.
I am currently trying to instantiate the vector in the wrapper,

```
private:
   std::vector<int>* outputVector
```

and in the constructor, I instantiate it :

```
outputVector = new std::vector<int>();
```

Now, in the wrapper method that calls the c++ library function :

```
m_pUnmanagedTPRTreeClass->GetInRegion(..., &outputVector)
```

I omitted the other parameters because they dont matter for this case. I can already use other functions of the library and they work without a problem. I just can't manage to pass a pointer to a std::vector.

With the code like this, I get the error message :

```
error C2664: 'TPSimpleRTree<CT,T>::GetInRegion' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'cli::interior_ptr<Type>' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'
```

I have tried removing the "&", as I am not great at C++ and am unsure how to correctly use pointers. Then, the error becomes :

```
error C2664: 'TPSimpleRTree<CT,T>::GetInRegion' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'std::vector<_Ty> *' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'
```

EDIT: I have tried replacing "&" by "*", it does not work, I get the error :

> cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'

The signature of the c++ function for the vector is so :

```
GetInRegion(..., std::vector<T*>& a_objects)
```

Comment: Do you really mean to pass the address of the pointer instead of just the pointer? What is the signature of `GetInRegion`? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should not need to `new` the vector at all, just declare it right before using in the function call, pass the address of the (non-pointer) vector, then marshal the data to a .Net collection after the function call.

Comment: ...scratch that! `GetInRegion` takes a *reference* to a `vector` of `T*`, so you've got it all backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the signature:

```
GetInRegion(..., std::vector<T*>& a_objects)
```

You would call this (in C++ or C++/CLI) like:

```
std::vector<int*> v;
m_pUnmanagedTPRTreeClass->GetInRegion(..., v);
```

Then you can manipulate the data as needed or marshall the data into a .Net container.

Comment: Thank you so much, the <T*> was hidden under a typedef in the library, I never noticed the implication of it. That fixed it!

Comment: Hello again crash, I wanted to send you a PM but I didn't figure out how, I am having trouble converting my std::vector<int*> into a type that can be used by managed C#. My trouble comes from the <int*> part, it wont let me convert when I try with either a List<int^>^ or an array<int^>. Could you give me some directions?

Comment: Assuming the `int *` is just a pointer to `int`, de-reference and save the `int`? Don't know anyting about the interface, so not sure how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

> 'std::vector<_Ty> *' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'

is self explanatory, you need to dereference instead of taking a pointer, so instead of:

```
 m_pUnmanagedTPRTreeClass->GetInRegion(..., &outputVector)
```

use:

```
 m_pUnmanagedTPRTreeClass->GetInRegion(..., *outputVector)
                                            ^~~~~~~!!
```

after your edit I see your getinregion signature is:

```
 GetInRegion(..., std::vector<T*>& a_objects)
```

so it accepts std::vector where T is a pointer, while you want to pass to getinregion a std::vector where int is not a pointer.

Comment: Hello, sorry for omitting that, but I have tried what you suggested. I get the same error, except its : 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'

Comment: @Storm see my edit, I admit that I dont know how far CLI might cause problems here.